# How to save date in Angular as a timestamp to Firestore?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am trying to save personal info of person with ***birth date and activation date*** into Firestore database in Angular;

However, passing object with `Date()` type fields the dates are saved as a string:

```
this.treatment.activationDate = new Date();
// gives such result in firestore with string type
// activationDate: "2018-11-16T09:48:51.137Z"
```

Also tried to use server timestamp, but the following method does not return valid value:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Result in Firestore (not allowed to upload images sorry :) ):

```
activationDate: (map)
     _methodName: FieldValue.serverTimestamp
```

However, this method can not provide me a timestamp for custom dates (birthDate for example)
***So what is the best way to save date as a timestamp object in firestore using angular?***

```
.....
import  * as firebase from 'firebase';
.....
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit { 
......

this.treatment.activationDate = new Date();
  //firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
  console.log("timestamp: ", this.treatment.activationDate,                  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()); 
  this.patientService.savePatient(this.patient, this.treatment,   this.courseMeds);
```

And a model:

```
export class CourseMed{
  amountPerDay: number;
  atc: String;
  name: String;
  days: number;
  dosage: number;
  form: String;
  method: String;
  periodicity: number;
  takeTimes: string[];
  used: number;
  takenCount: {};
```

angular 6
Node: 8
rxjs 6.3.3
typescript  2.9.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want in your Cloud Firestore database the date value of:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

You should use a call to [.toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) function. Please checkout [FireStore Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp/) from the official documentation for more information. In your particular case, you should use the following call:

```
treatment.activationDate.toDate()
```

This change was added in [Firebase JS SDK `v4.13.0`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#cloud-firestore_7), where JavaScript `Date` objects should be saved of type `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 2):

Since my date was converted into string at some point, I converted it back to Date object just before it is being saved to the database.

```
let myDate = new Date();
// myDate is converted to string at some point.
```

Just before I save it to firebase, I needed to convert it again to Date object.

```
// need to parse from String to Date
let myDateTemp = new Date(myDate);
record = {
    myDate: myDateTemp
}
return this.firestore.collection('myCollection').add(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

I save my data to firestore and use new Date(). The date is currently added as a timestamp to firestore.

But you can use moment.js in your app to handle the string. moment('my date in a string format') will be converted as you like.