# How can I keep track of the last updated at time for a document in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, triggers, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have an `updatedAt` field in my `pizza` document that should be updated every time there's an update happening in this particular document. I think the best place to handle this is in an `onUpdate` trigger:

```
exports.onUpdatePizza = functions.firestore
  .document('pizzas/{pizzaId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    return change.after.ref.update({ updatedAt: new Date() });
});
```

However, the above code will fall into an infinite loop. How can I implement this without the undesired side effect?

Comment: I would use the firebase server timestamp for this, no need for a function. I mention it in a previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53483507/1614889

Comment: I have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60207286/5295747

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation there https://medium.com/@krngd2/prevent-infinity-loop-in-firebase-cloud-functions-ea8083afbd35

Comment: This would be a good answer if you cite or paraphrase the relevant information from the post. That way its not reliant on a link.

Answer (score 1):

Add this inside the function:

```js
// simply input data
const after: any = change.after.exists ? change.after.data() : null;
const before: any = change.before.exists ? change.before.data() : null;

const canUpdate = () => {
    // if Update Trigger
    if (before.updatedAt && after.updatedAt) {
        if (after.updatedAt._seconds !== before.updatedAt._seconds) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // if Create Trigger <--- assuming you use it
    if (!before.createdAt && after.createdAt) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

if (canUpdate()) {
   // update code here
}
```

Here is my code for universal updates: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60963531/271450

Answer (score 0):

In your function, check to see if the update date is within some threshhold of the current time before updating it again.  This will defend against unwanted writes, but the downside is that the update time may lag by that threshold, if there are very frequent updates.