# How to store DateTime using cloud function in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store DateTime using cloud function. I sent this from client side.

```
taskData: {
            'dueDateTime': dateTime,
            'nullDueDate': false,
            'willNotify': false,
            'notificationDateTime': null,
          },
```

And this is how sent the data to cloud function.

```
HttpsCallable callable =
    FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('updateTask');
await callable.call({
  'taskID': taskID,
  'authorID': authorID,
  'users': users,
  'taskData': taskData,
});
```

I am getting error and it's thrown from flutter side, I am not getting any error from cloud function.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart': Failed assertion: line 55 pos 10: 'parameter == null ||
      parameter is String ||
      parameter is num ||
      parameter is bool': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
#2      _assertValidParameterType
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:55
#3      _assertValidParameterType.<anonymous closure>
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:52
Reloaded 0 of 1208 libraries in 133ms.
Reloaded 33 of 1208 libraries in 791ms.
Reloaded 40 of 1208 libraries in 758ms.
Reloaded 40 of 1208 libraries in 695ms.
#4      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
#5      _assertValidParameterType
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:52
#6      _assertValidParameterType.<anonymous closure>
package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:52
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
#8      _assertValidParameterType (pac<…>
```

It not necessary since no error on cloud function but here is my Type Script code. If it comment the `//'dueDateTime': dateTime,` then I have no issue.

```
const taskData = data['taskData'];
batch.update(userAssignedTaskPath, taskData);
```

When I used client side code to update firestore it converted DateTime to Timestamp and everything worked fine. I even tried to convert DateTime to Timestamp and sent it to the function `Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime)` but didn't work.

**Updated on 9 Jan 21:** I found the solution here. If you wanna see the code let me know I will post. [Convert date to timestamp for storing into firebase firestore in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482750/convert-date-to-timestamp-for-storing-into-firebase-firestore-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to convert this into a string with `.toIso8601String()`

To get it back from Firestore, use `DateTime.parse(snap.data()['myDate']),`

Comment: I can do `dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch` to store but the problem is I already have stored my dateTime as Timestamp. 
`dueDateTime: data['dueDateTime'] != null ? (data['dueDateTime'] as Timestamp).toDate() : null,`

Comment: If I interpret the error correctly, this is because you are sending the wrong data type to Firestore, which would be DateTime. Try `"date":Timestamp.fromDate(dateTime)`