# How can I convert timestamp to date and convert date to timestamp after editing provided by firebase?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working with cloud functions. Actually, I am a flutter amateur, but cloud functions require JavaScript, so I don't have any Idea.
I am getting a timestamp from this code.

```
admin.firestore.Timestamp.now()
```

But I want to edit the timestamp and upload it to another collection.
I want to convert the current month to the next month.
i.e. - February to March and upload to another document.

Thanks a lot in Advance!

Comment: Dates are pretty well covered on SO. If you search each of those steps separately I'd bet you'll find answers that help.

Comment: Sorry, But I researched a lot, but any of the solutions are not working for me, Maybe I am dumb.

Comment: I'd start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/parsing-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: And finish here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482750/convert-date-to-timestamp-for-storing-into-firebase-firestore-in-javascript

Comment: Let us know if there aren't appropriate solutions there and we'll consider reopening the question.